# FFmpeg audio phase reversal

Tags: ffmpeg, sox

I'm writing a script which performs a series of operations on several `.wav` files. One of the operations is *phase reversal* (from what I gather, a 180 degrees phase shift).

Is this possible with FFmpeg and, if so, what is the switch I need to use?

On a sidenote:
I have found a possible way to reverse phase with SOX here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682730/sound-sox-how-can-i-make-a-180-degrees-phase-shifted-version-of-an-audio-file (though, why it uses the volume switch is beyond me), but after spending several hours trying to figure this out with FFmpeg, I would still like to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To invert phase, you need to use the `aeval` filter.

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "aeval='-val(0)':c=same" output.wav
```

`val(0)` references the first channel. The -ve sign inverts phase. `c=same` preserves the input channel layout (in the output).

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work. I tested by mixing an original `.wav` with a processed one and they cancelled-out as expected.

Another way of doing this, seems to be this: `ffmpeg -i input.wav -af pan="1c:c0=-1*c0" -ac 1 output.wav`, but I find the `aeval` method easier to process (for my brain, that is).

Comment: Source of the previous method: http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2806&p=8414

Comment: The advantage of the `aeval` method is that if you don't know the channel layout of the source, it still works.

Comment: This will probably come in handy, since I'm not even sure how many channels I will have to deal with.

Comment: What does `-ve` sign here refer to, as it's not in the command itself.

Comment: Negative sign , as in `-val(0)`