# Why is my YouTube video distorted on so many mobile devices?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, youtube, mobile-phone

A few hours after I uploaded an [FFmpeg-encoded YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DU4rSCfkhs), the few people that I had sent it to started reporting a strange issue: that the first 26 minutes of the audio sounded very distorted; some have described it as sounding like it's underwater. Here's [an example](https://i.imgur.com/pxColLl.mp4) of what it sounds like.

I then started testing with more people, and came up with the following data from a total of 31 mobile devices.

**Normal Audio:**

```
Galaxy S10 (x2)
Galaxy S20 (x3)
Galaxy A50
iPhone XR (x3)
iPhone 7
iPhone 8 (x2)
iPhone 10 Pro
iPhone 11
iPhone 11 Pro
iPhone 11 Pro Max
iPhone 12 (x3)
iPhone 12 Pro
Oppo F11
OnePlus 7T
Pixel 3A XL
OnePlus 7 Pro
```

**Distorted Audio:**

```
iPhone 6S
Galaxy S7 Edge
Galaxy S8+
Galaxy S10 Lite
Huawei Y6 2019
Huawei P30 Pro
Honor 10 Lite
```

The audio for those first 26 minutes is broken for 7 out of 31 mobile devices, so 22%, and this increases to more than 50% when only Android phones are included. Most of those I asked were based in developed countries, which means that the data also skews towards newer, more modern phones, which means that figure could easily be closer to 80% in less developed countries that primarily use older Androids.

Needless to say, this is a pretty big problem for someone like me who expected to be able to upload to YouTube and let it handle the rest instead of doing web-dev-like device debugging.

I compiled the video from several source videos, encoding and concatenating them using FFmpeg.

It uses H264 and OPUS as codecs, but more relevantly, checking the [source video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4wVfnFpIbw) that those first 26 minutes comes from shows that this problem originates in that video, so now the question becomes:

**a) What is it in that particular source video that is causing the audio to become garbled in such a large proportion of mobile devices?**

**b) How can I fix it using FFmpeg?**

Comment: Mobile devices are off topic.

Comment: Unfairly closed because the issue presenting on mobile may only be a coincidence, and you may actually be encountering a bug on YouTube (or perhaps a FFmpeg problem) related to messy concatenation. But I'm just throwing out guesses. If you [edit] the question to focus on the ffmpeg command then it should be re-opened. Show the ffmpeg command and the complete log. If you used the concat demuxer please show info on each of the inputs listed in the concat text file.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have to agree with llogan here. Voted to reopen.

Comment: I think the problem here is a normalization issue. The audio comes in too loud, the more modern phones all have volume normalization build in and correct the problem, the older phones do not and thus sound very distorted. The solution is going to be, next time, ensure that the volume is not too loud. Leave in headroom so the audio can peak normally. This will require some testing to find the optimal setting. You do not want it to be too loud, yet also not too soft. Youtube compression algorithm will destroy your audio too if you compress it too much.

Comment: Also, seeing the problem video, they are just on a low quality stream, possibly due to youtube still processing the video. General Rule of thumb for YouTube, if Quality matters, release the video in private setting, wait for the processing to be finished and only then share the link, to ensure it is shared in a higher resolution.

Comment: @llogan I agree with you that this is primarily an FFmpeg question which is why I posted it here, and I will be opening a thread in meta for it as soon as I can, but I don't think the issue is a YouTube or FFmpeg bug because it's also present in the source video linked above. My focus for this question was how to use FFmpeg to solve whatever the problem is with that source video.

Comment: @LPChip The source video in question - where the issue originates from and whose audio is also broken in the same way - is from 2011. I don't think this is down to partial processing.

Comment: If its not processing, then they play back the video on a very low quality. So either they raise the quality to something higher than their phone supports just to get clearer audio, or they can't listen to it. The problem video clearly shows low quality footage. Its possible they can't get a higher bitrate due to being on mobile. Ask them to connect to wifi and try again on a higher quality setting.

Comment: @llogan This has now been reopened, thanks to everyone who voted to reopen it.

Comment: So the original source video (not the one on YouTube) also plays weird in mobile? Or only after you process it with ffmpeg? Or only after you upload the ffmpeg output to YouTube? Is it only mobile with problems? You need to do some elimination of variables to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @llogan No, the [source video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4wVfnFpIbw) is distorted in the same way. There is no better source video given that it was 10 years ago, so that video is the closest thing I had to an original source, and the first 26 mins of it forms the first 26 mins of my video. I used FFmpeg to encode my own uploaded version of it, but since the problems exist in the original 2011 video, the problem can't be FFmpeg (except in the very, very unlikely event the original uploader also used FFmpeg to encode). (cont...)

Comment: I posted this question in the hope that it would be possible to determine what's wrong with that source video and use FFmpeg to fix it in my own encode. The fact that the audio is only garbled for the older phones that were tested, suggests something in that source video is needed that is missing on older mobile devices - codec support or the like - but I wouldn't know how to go about checking. And yes, so far only those devices listed have presented problems, all of them mobile phones. Smart TVs, laptops and desktops have all worked fine.

Comment: Still need to narrow down the problem. First step is find out which of the 18 available combinations of formats available for this video are giving you trouble. Which formats are the phones requesting? Do the audio only formats also have problems? Do they work if they play the file locally, directly on the phone? Is this the only video that has this problem? See the `-F` and `-f` options in `man youtube-dl`. Perhaps the question really is off-topic and is limited to mobile and there is nothing to be done, but regardless I still think it was closed too early before more info was available.

Comment: @llogan Even if the cause of the issue is limited to mobile it still doesn't make the question off-topic, since it's primarily a question about using the FFmpeg software to solve the problem. Even the fact that there may be no solution at all doesn't itself make the question off-topic. I'll look into seeing what I can do to answer those variables, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this was downvoted, but regardless, I managed to find a fix for the problem by posting the exact same question to the Doom9 audio specialists forum. I got the following response almost immediately from the user *lvqcl*:

> Left and right channels are 180° out of phase. Invert one of them (the first 26 minutes of one of the channels, that is).

When I asked him why the problem was limited to certain mobile devices, he responded:

> It seems that they play audio in mono, so they add left and right channels together. So the result contains only audio compression artifacts from left and right channels.

I then set about searching how to fix this in FFmpeg and came across the following command, courtesy of Gyan [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1066644/ffmpeg-audio-phase-reversal):

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "aeval='-val(0)':c=same" output.wav
```

Running this command on the source video in question, re-concatenating all the source videos, re-uploading to YouTube, and then testing again with the same devices, confirms that this has indeed fixed the issue.

I was glad to be able to upload my video to YouTube without worrying about individual device support, having dealt with that enough in my web development work. Thanks to everyone who voted to keep this question open against the wishes of this site's increasingly overzealous moderators.

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down and posting super helpful info. My problem was from Apple FinalCutX, not ffmpeg, but same result. Stereo audio is totally phased out when played through Android as mono. I modified the original audio to mono and exported that way.